# Relative file reading works on Windows but Not Mac

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

Background:
Recently I've been working on a program that performs some data analysis on an input data file (given by the user as a full path or the name if it is in a folder called inputFiles that the program creates) and spits out a bunch of output data files (using CSV).

Issue:
The issue I'm running into is that when I run the .jar on my Windows machine, it will create 3 folders (InputFiles, TempFiles, and OutPutFiles) but when the program is on a Mac, the GUI starts but no folders are created. Another issue is the program will read in input data from a given CSV file perfectly fine on Windows, but on Mac, the program spits out a file not found exception no matter if the full file path is given or if the file.

Below, I've attached the links to pictures of the code that creates the folders on startup and the code that is used to create a FileReader given a path or file name.

[Creation of file reader - filePath is what the user inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftd4H.png)

[Creation of three folders the program uses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Zwu.png)

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

 You *can't know* where those directories will be (or whether you're *allowed* to create them) because you can't know where the [current directory](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java) is one you've given over your jar. Use directories off `user.home`

Answer (score 0):

```
user.home
└── YourApp
    ├── InputFiles
    ├── OutputFiles
    └── TempFiles
```

is the sort of tree you should have. Obviously that's not the literal 'user.home', but the value of `System.getProperty("user.home");`